# Database contains duplicate entries from a Set<String>

Tags: java, jpa, entity, set

In my application, I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Commentable implements Serializable {
    ... 
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    protected Set<String> likers = new HashSet<String>();
    ...
}
```

Whenever a user clicks the like button, I will add his username into the above `Set` to make sure that he can never like the same post twice. However, when I look at the database, I saw the same username appears many times.

If I call `likers.size()`, I still can get the unique number of likes from the `Set`. Nevertheless, the following query will always return the bigger number:

```
Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(L) FROM Commentable C JOIN C.likers L WHERE C.id = :id");
q1.setParameter("id", commentableID);
long numberOfLikes = (Long) q1.getSingleResult();
System.out.println("HERE " + numberOfLikes);
```

The database contains entries like the following:

```
# |  Commentable_ID  |  LIKERS
1 |       1801       |  Mr.James
2 |       1801       |  Mr.James
3 |       1801       |  Mr.James
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As suggested by JMelnik, I tried to put in the unique constraint:

```
@Entity
public class Commentable implements Serializable {
    ... 
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    @Column(unique=true)
    protected Set<String> likers = new HashSet<String>();

    public void addLiker(String liker) {
        this.likers.add(liker);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I click the like button for the 2nd time, GlassFish threw me the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'jamesboyz' for key 'LIKERS'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO Commentable_LIKERS (Commentable_ID, LIKERS) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="INSERT INTO Commentable_LIKERS (Commentable_ID, LIKERS) VALUES (?, ?)")
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'jamesboyz' for key 'LIKERS'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

In one of my `SessionBean`, I have the following method for recording likes:

```
@Override
public int like(long commentableID, String liker) {
    Commentable c = em.find(Commentable.class, commentableID);
    if (c == null) return STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
    else {
        c.addLiker(liker);
        return STATUS_SUCCESSFUL;
    }
}
```

I'd be very grateful if you could tell me why this happens and how I can avoid duplicate entries in the database.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: The username appears multiple times for the ***same*** commentable? Please show some sample output of that from the database.

Comment: Try putting unique constraint on @Column and on database column (if not auto generated tables). Then remove duplicated entries from database and then try some testdrive or smth.

Comment: @Perception I have just updated my post, is that what you need?

Comment: @JMelnik Please see my update above.

Comment: Please provide code where you add item to the Set of likers and persist it.

Comment: Looks like hibernate does not clear previous values. How you handle transactions? I use HibernateTransactionManager and in my case when I update entity with @ElementCollection first hibernate delete all existing elements and than insert new one. But this works only with hibernate transaction manager

Comment: For temporary solution you can check set contains such a value, and if not - add. Or catch duplicate exception and throw validation error such as "you already liked".

Comment: @JMelnik: I have just updated my post.

Comment: @alexey28: I'm using `EclipseLink`, not `Hibernate`

Comment: I think eclipselink is trying to persist all of the Set again. Try this: before an item to Set, print out the contents of the Set, then add item to Set and print out content again. If the items in set are not duplicated, then it is problem with persisting/merging the Set. Try .merge() instead of .persist(), if it works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, if you change your addLiker method to,

```
public void addLiker(String liker) {
    this.likers.size();
    this.likers.add(liker);
}
```

Then it will work.  I remember this being an issue, but thought it was fixed.  Can you try the 2.4 milestone build.  Otherwise log a bug, or find and vote for the existing one.

You should also be able to fix it making the relationship EAGER, or using @ChangeTracking(DEFERRED) in the entity.
  You could also use,

```
public void addLiker(String liker) {
    if (!this.likers.contains(liker)) {
        this.likers.add(liker);
    }
}
```